# Do supply lines work together?

Tags: fallout-4

Say I have three settlements: A, B, and C

A has all my wood.
B has all my steel.
C has all my rubber.

Now if I set up a supply line from B to A and from C to A, A has access to all three.  But does B or C have access to all three?  Or do I need to also set up a supply line from B to C?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, supply lines are [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). [Reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) too, I suppose. This makes it an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), meaning that you can see the same supplies at all connected settlements.

In other words, if you set up a supply line from Sanctuary to the Red Rocket Station, and one from the Red Rocket Station to the Starlight Drive-In, you can access the supplies from all three locations at all three locations.

Comment: Oh boy. I did not know this and have a tangled web of provisioners.

Comment: @MikeCole Perhaps you had a [complete graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteGraph.html)? A [connected graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html) is sufficient. It's nice when all those math classes actually help someone.

Comment: Yep, the complete graph is what I was aiming for. I started reassigning provisioners when I saw them in camps. Gonna be a mess to clean up. Related: when you reassign a Provisioner, their name doesn't change back to Settler.

Comment: I have a math degree, thank you for explaining like this

Comment: I just connect every location to sanctuary hill. It's not like travel speed affects them. Traffic in front of santuary hill might become a bit grid locked.